# Convert SQL to eloquent query

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

i have the next query with subequery how can convert it to eloquent, i have some troubles with eloquent conversion :S. Thanks

```
select a.* from (
    select * 
    from "public"."tabla_procesados" 
    where "state" LIKE '%Failed%' 
    and id_execution = (select max(id_execution) from public.tabla_procesados)
    order by public.tabla_procesados.ts_start_processing desc limit 1
) a
where ts_start_processing < (now() - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DB::query()` returns an instance of the query builder.

From that instance, you can call `from(table, alias)` to set the main table the query is using. For subqueries, `table` can be another query builder containing the subquery, or a Closure.

You can also call `DB::table(table, alias)`. It's the same as `DB::query()->from(table, alias)`. `alias` is optional unless `table` is a subquery.

---

Using a query builders for every subquery:

```php
$max = DB::query()
    ->selectRaw('max(id_execution)')
    ->from('public.tabla_procesados');

$sub = DB::query()
    ->from('public.tabla_procesados')
    ->where('state', 'like', '%Failed%')
    ->where('id_execution', $max)
    ->orderByDesc('public.tabla_procesados.ts_start_procesing')
    ->limit(1);

$query = DB::query()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from($sub, 'a')
    ->whereRaw("ts_start_processing < (now() - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL");
```

Using Closures whenever possible:

```php
$query = DB::query()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from(function ($sub) {
        $sub->from('public.tabla_procesados')
            ->where('state', 'like', '%Failed%')
            ->where('id_execution', function ($max) {
                $max->selectRaw('max(id_execution)')
                    ->from('public.tabla_procesados');
            })
            ->orderByDesc('public.tabla_procesados.ts_start_procesing')
            ->limit(1);
    }, 'a')
    ->whereRaw("ts_start_processing < (now() - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL");
```

---

Executing the query

```
// string containing actual SQL that will be executed. Use to check if the query is the same.
$sql = $query->toSql();
// Execute query and get results into a Collection
$results = $query->get();
```

Comment: Note Laravel provides [`fromSub()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub) and [`selectSub()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectSub) methods for subqueries.